# Wordpress ajax call returns entire html page, but not always

Tags: wordpress

If I logged in on localhost, then it returns ok, but when I loggen in in Incognito page, then it returns entire page. When I logged in as admin on server web-site, it returns ok, but when I loggen in as subscriber - it returns entire page. What is this??

PHP

```
         add_action('wp_ajax_load_more_kvitna', [$this, 'load_more_kvitna']);
         add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_kvitna', [$this, 'load_more_kvitna']);
         add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'add_kvitna_script']);
                 
public function add_kvitna_script()
            { 
        
wp_enqueue_script('kvitna-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/konkursantka.js', ['jquery'], time(), true);
        
                wp_localize_script('kvitna-js', 'KVITNA', [
                    'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
                    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'),
                    
        
                ]);
        }

public function load_more_kvitna() {
         wp_send_json_success([
    
                'files_2' => $_FILES, //for example
                // 'form' => $form
            ]);
    }
```

js

```
 $.ajax({
              url: KVITNA.ajax_url,
              type: "POST",
              data: {
                action: "load_more_kvitna",
                
                nonce: KVITNA.nonce,
             
              },
            })
              .then((res) => {
console.log(res) //entire html page
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, `admin_init` action actually affect on `admin-ajax.php`, i didn't know that. And I had some code to redirect non-admin users from admin area, and what i did is added wp_doing_ajax() to my admin_init action:

```
add_action('admin_init', [$this, 'subscriber_redirect_admin']);
      public function subscriber_redirect_admin()
        {
            if (!wp_doing_ajax() && current_user_can('subscriber')) {
                wp_redirect(home_url());
                exit;
            }
        }
```

And now works fine. I won't delete this post, maybe someone got same problem.